# Should user credentials be saved into same entity as user?

Tags: java, database, credentials

There are 2 entities `user` and `credentials` which are used in web site authorizarion. Should `user` entity contains `credentials` or it is better to store these entities in separate table/entities?

Comment: Have users only a single credential entry? If so then you could add them in the same table if not then use a new table and reference the user as foreign key.

Comment: Is your question about security or database layout?